# Constructor is not public for Android API 24 GNSSMeasurement

Tags: java, android

I am new to `Java` and the `android SDK`, so I apologize in advance if something is terribly wrong. This is my first attempt in doing something using `Java` and `Android`

I am using `API 24` and trying to create a simple app to print the GNSS measurements to the screen (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssMeasurement.html). When I try and create a new GNSSMeasurement I get;

> "'GNSSMeasurement()' is not public. Cannot be accessed from outside package".

So far I have just been using the empty template project in `Android Studio` and trying to modify and display to the screen.

```
import android.location.GnssMeasurement;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // This is where I get the error
    GnssMeasurement newMeasure = new GnssMeasurement();
    // Somehow display to screen or log to file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not create instances of that yourself. Instead, if I understand the documentation correctly, you need to:

- Get a `LocationManager` via `getSystemService()`
- Register [a `GnssMeasurementsEvent.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssMeasurementsEvent.Callback.html) object with the `LocationManager` [via `registerGnssMeasurementsCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#registerGnssMeasurementsCallback(android.location.GnssMeasurementsEvent.Callback))
- In your callback's `onGnssMeasurementsReceived()` method, you will get [a `GnssMeasurementsEvent` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssMeasurementsEvent.html), which has a `getMeasurements()` method, which gives you a `Collection<GnssMeasurement>` response, representing some GNSS measurements that you can use